# regexp seach over string_view retrieving result by reference

Tags: c++

I want to parse over an existing buffer (string) and pick some sub-match expressions purely by referral, without any creation of intermittent heap copies. My understanding is that the regular-expression machinery internally works entirely with pointers or references to the original data (is that correct?). Indeed it is possible to start a search (or an iterator) from `begin` and `end` iterators. However, the sub-match only seems to expose an `operator string_type()`.

Probably I am overlooking something obvious... maybe some specialisation? Or is the only way to construct something with the help of the `position(i)` and `length(i)` functions of the main match?

---

*currently I am on C++17 with an upgrade to c++20 planned*

Comment: Every [`sub_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) inherits from `std::pair` a pair of iterators that point to the beginning and end of the matched sub-string. For an `std::string`, these would be `std::string::const_iterator`